# hdfs dfs -ls No Display

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I installed cloudera quickstart vm on docker. On HDFS Web UI five folders (benchmarks, hbase, tmp, user and var) are listed but when I use

> hdfs dfs -ls

or

> hadoop fs -ls

commands. It displays any directory. Any solution?

Comment: What error message/stack trace do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it shows your HDFS home folder (which often is empty on a fresh installation).

If you want to show the root of HDFS (which is what the web ui shows), add `/` to the end of either command